# Make Qt application standard application for RSS feeds

Tags: qt, firefox, rss

Lets say I wanna read Reuters feeds and use this url for that http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml.

Firefox then asks me if I want to subscribe to them using some program. How can I make my developed program in C++ with Qt available to that list (would be nice, if it would be platform independent and not some Windows/Mac/Linux hack)?

[image: Screenshot of Firefox, asking which program should be used for displaying to a feed]

Comment: I think you would need to create a Firefox Plugin that registered as a feed handler (see [Adding feed readers to Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Adding_feed_readers_to_Firefox)). The plugin would then notify your application of the new feed, for example by launching it (or a helper app) with specific command line parameters. I don't know enough details to write a proper answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to have people download your feed reader application, then have them select it as the default reader for the MIME type in the browser. In Firefox you can configure an external app as a RSS reader via Edit > Preferences > Applications > set "Web Feed" handler to the location of your feed reader application/script. Or you can do it from the default RSS view, as shown in your post. Firefox will then pass that application the URL of the feed as the first parameter on the command line. That's it.

Try setting your feed reader to this script for example (Linux):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$@ `date` \n" >>/tmp/ff-feed.txt
gdialog --backtitle "Feed Reader" --msgbox "Foo Feeds!" 10 40
```

-

```
cat /tmp/ff-feed.txt 
Sat Jun  7 13:27:36 EST 2014
feed://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews?format=xml
```

If you want RSS handled in browser you have to write a web app or plugin and register it - see [registerContentHandler()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.registerContentHandler) for details.

Comment: You are right I got `feed://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture?format=xml` as a command line argument.